# iphone how to send my project build to someone else

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, ios-provisioning, udid

my work colleague is asking me to send a build so that he can install the application on his phone to test it.  I need to send this application to him today. a build that is. not the actualy project just the correct files needed so he can install it on his iphone.

Heres what I've done.
Ive added his UDID to a new device in the provisioning portal.
then i created a new provisioning profile with my app id.

On the provisioning portal there is an option in the profile section next to that new profile i just created where i can download the profile onto my desktop.

What do do from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps on the portal to creating an ad hoc build and certificate.

Look at the following link, will require login to Apple.

http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/distribution.action

Answer (score 0):

Craig Hockenberry gives an excellent write up on beta testing with ad hoc provisioning here as well: http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/

Answer (score 0):

Use TestFlight: I've blogged about [Getting mobile app builds to your customers](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2013/04/02/getting-mobile-app-builds-to-your-customers/) which includes a brief tutorial with screenshots on how to use TestFlight.