# Apple certificate for developer

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am newbie in iOS app development. I have developed a iOS app. I would like to send my build file to someone. But I am not sure where can I find my build file.

I heard that I have to have one **Apple certificate** in order to build, what is that **Apple Certificate** ? How & where can I get it? (I have already signed in in Apple Developer space)

Comment: build file or .ipa file?

Comment: http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/docs/buildiosapp/buildiosapp.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you beta test an iphone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app)

Comment: [use this link you learn to send build to other person][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935740/iphone-how-to-send-my-project-build-to-someone-else

Answer (score 4):

I have already signedup with ios developer account, you should have access to ios Provisionng protal. (https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)

If you are not able to see this, You are not member fo developer portal yet. To get access of this section, You need to complete the registration process.
Please make sure you have paid the fees (generally US $99 for the enrolment)
Create Apple Developer Account
http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

iOS Dev Center
http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

After registration, You will get access to all detail including how to create certificate and provision profiles.
https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have already signed than go to

1. https://developer.apple.com/
2. Member center
3. iOS Provisioning Portal
4. Certificates
5. Create new certificate and download it

Comment: I have download it (the development cert. not the distribution one), what's next?

Comment: Just click on it. I will be added to keychain access, or what problem do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You need that certificate to install profile in your mac. Profile is needed to make an adhoc build of your project to be sent to someone. You need to sign your code with that profile.

If you have signed up with apple developer program that requires $100 a year, you can generate certificate and profiles from there

Answer (score 1):

if you already registered to Apple Development Program follow the steps:

1. login to www.developer.com/membercenter
2. click ios provisioning profile
3. create certificate using keychain access
4. use certificate create development certificate
5. see how to steps in provisoning tab and create Distrubution
   Certificate
6. drag and Drop downloaded certificates to xcode and itunes in dock
7. open your application
8. go to build settings
9. under code signing add distribution certificate
10. select ios device to build
11. go to file -> project settings -> navigate to derived data path
     there you get your build file send across the person you want to.

Comment: THanks, but I did not find the 8)go to build settings. where is it ???

Comment: BUT, There is NO 9)code signing and distribution certificate, under build settings of xcode.